# Pivot Table in Pandas DataFrame - Make rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, pivot-table

So I have a dataframe where the state is the US state codes and the year columns have values for that particular state, the data frame has values for all the states, is there a way I can pivot so that there is an ""Year"" column for all the years and values are in just one column.

```
My current dataframe :

STATE YEAR2021 YEAR2022 YEAR2023 ....
XX        XX       XX       XX

Desired DataFrame:

STATE YEAR VALUE
XX    2021  XX
XX    2022  XX
XX    2023  XX
```

How do I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
df2 = (df.set_index('STATE')
         .stack()
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'level_1': 'YEAR',
                          0: 'VALUE'})
      )
df2['YEAR'] = df2['YEAR'].str[4:]
```

input:

```
  STATE YEAR2021 YEAR2022 YEAR2023
0    AA       XX       YY       ZZ
```

output:

```
  STATE  YEAR VALUE
0    AA  2021    XX
1    AA  2022    YY
2    AA  2023    ZZ
```

Comment: works like a charm, I would dissect it later but if you can you explain it would be great.

Comment: I suggest you run each step in the pipeline one by one to see the progression. To summarize the key step is `stack` that moves columns to rows, the rest is accessory to it.